# JSON I/O across Scala.js and Scala on JVM

Tags: javascript, json, scala, playframework, scala.js

I have a Scala Play Framework/Scala.js project where the server is Play compiled to JVM and the client is compiled via Scala.js to JavaScript. There are some shared classes used by both server and client which are compiled to both JVM and JavaScript. Server and client communicate by encoding shared classes in JSON. Is it possible to write JSON I/O code such that is is compiled to JavaScript's JSON.stringify/JSON.parse on the client side, but some Scala JSON library on the server side? Thanks!

Comment: It's not terribly clear to me what you are asking. Can you show an example, and perhaps break up your paragraph into what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Play JSON is already compatible with Scala.JS si without more detail this question is pointless

Comment: More generally, pretty much all of the major JSON libraries -- Play-JSON, Circe, uPickle, etc -- run on both ScalaJVM and Scala.js.  So just pick a library and go for it...

Comment: @JustinduCoeur If I use any of these libraries in Scala.js, will they rely on JSON.stringify/JSON.parse? Or will the entire rendering/parsing code be translated to JavaScript?

Comment: To give an example, before Scala.js, I have `case class User(id: Int, name: String)`, and instance `User(42, "Trillian")` is serialized to `{ id: 42, name: "Trillian" }`, which in JavaScript I can parse using `JSON.parse`.
So I'm assuming the most efficient way to get a User instance would be to do something like `JSON.parse("...").asInstanceOf[User]`. It seems like massive overkill to compile a Scala library to JavaScript to do something that JavaScript already does natively.

Comment: @OliverRuebenacker You don't want to use JSON.stringify or JSON.parse when serializing and deserializing Scala.js classes.  JSON only supports data structures, not instances of classes.  By using the Scala.js serialization libraries, you can deserialize JSON into instances of scala classes with all of their methods readily available.

If you're concerned about performance, maybe [BooPickle](https://boopickle.suzaku.io/) would interest you.  It uses binary serialization instead of JSON and runs much faster than JSON alternatives.

Comment: The Scala JSON libraries are mostly pretty optimized to work sensibly.  In particular, for example, uPickle uses the native JSON capabilities under the hood when it is running in the browser.  I think you're worrying about a non-issue here.  (And as Ben says, if speed is your priority, you should probably use Boopickle instead.)